# Insert space or enter in sqlite in ios sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, uitextview

I want to insert space or enter in sqlite database.
Is their any way to insert the space or enter.
Can we do it by ascii character.

We can do it by using nsattributed string and but can we do it by nsstring?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply use `\t` (space - tab) or `\n` (enter - new line) with `NSString`.

e.g. `NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is an example\nTo show you the great things\t:D"];` and you can save it into your db, when you show it in a `UILabel` or `UITextView` `\n` and `\t`will convert to new line or tab space.

Update: even you can use html tags for this, use `&nbsp;` (space) and `<br>` for new line. Or some other tags, `<pre>` to show **preformated** text.

I'm not sure whether sqlite deny escape characters for space and new line, in case you can replay them with html tags.

Comment: Thanks of the quick answer.But i dont want to display in uilablel.I want to store this in sqlite.And sqlite doesnot have any escape character of back-forward slash

Comment: I had tried using HTML tags.It is not working in sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this issue by below code:-

```
- (BOOL)textView:(CustomTextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{     
str_Notes=[str_Notes stringByAppendingString:text];    //Where str_Notes is NSstring
return YES;

}
```

And then i use string in my insert query. and i is working perfectly fine.